# How to connect my new Xamarin application to an existent azure DB?

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database

I started developing a new Cross-Platform app with Xamarin. 
For other projects my teammates created an azureDB with certain tables that I want to Query for my new Application. Can anyone tell me how to connect my new app to the AzureDB?

Thanks!

Comment: You should not connect directly to a database from your mobile app! Look at documentation.

Comment: Please take a look at Azure Mobile App Service and also, there's no such thing as AzureDB.  Do you mean Azure SQL Dabase? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/app-service/mobile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to connect to the database is using an API that will manage the interaction with the database. On [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106622/Building-REST-services-with-ASP-NET-Core-Web-API-a) article you will find how to build a REST API to access an Azure SQL Database.